# dynamic radio group to checkchangelistener is not working and also not showing/viewing

Tags: android, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I created the radio buttons dynamically and set them in the radio group and it is working good but when i click the radio buttons to get the value but onclick is not working here is the code: in this when i click on checked change listner there is nothing happens i also taost it to show either onclick is working or not but nothing prints. please help thanks in advance.

```
   try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        voterNA=dbcon.GetVoterNA(id);

        LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.NLinearLayout);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        ImageView iv=null;//new ImageView(context);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams prams=new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        prams.setMargins(2, 2, 2, 2);

        rg=new RadioGroup(context);
        ll.setLayoutParams(prams);
        rg.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        rg.setLayoutParams(prams);

        rg=dbcon.showNationalCan(rg, context,iv,voterNA);

        ll.addView(rg);

        rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                for(int i=0; i<group.getChildCount();i++)
                {
                    RadioButton rbtn=(RadioButton)group.getChildAt(i);
                    if(rbtn.getId()==checkedId)
                    {
                        serial=rbtn.getId();
                        Toast.makeText(context, serial, 1).show();
                        flag=true;
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Else", 1).show();

                        rbtn.setChecked(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

in above code i want to get the id of the radio button
here is the function by which the radio buttons are created.

```
    public RadioGroup showNationalCan(RadioGroup rg,Context context,ImageView iv,String voterNA){

    //candidate address  as punjab kpk etc

    if(conn==null){

    }
    try{
        RadioButton rb;
        Statement st=conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from AM_NATIONAL where ca_na=N'"+voterNA+"'");
        while (rs.next()) {
            rb=new RadioButton(context);
            rb.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            rb.setId(rs.getInt(1));
            rb.setText(rs.getString(2)+"\n"+rs.getString(3)+"\n");

            iv=new ImageView(context);
            byte[] photo=rs.getBytes(4);
            Bitmap bitmap;
            bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photo, 0, photo.length);
            iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            //rb.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.blank, 0, 0, 0);
            rg.addView(iv);
            rg.addView(rb);
        }
        rs.close();
        st.close();

    } catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rg;
}
```

is setid() and settext() can be called separately?

here is the xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/background3"
tools:context=".NationalActivity" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/NscrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/NLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10sp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Nokimagebtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/necpbin" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Nbackimagebtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/back" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Nexitimagebtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/exit" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the logcat when app crash now after updating the code:

```
09-02 17:31:11.769: W/dalvikvm(31156): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ff2908)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RadioGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:311)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:318)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15264)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15264)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4916)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15264)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15264)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4916)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2161)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15264)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2129)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1240)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1433)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1125)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4607)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:747)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:567)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:536)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:733)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
09-02 17:31:11.789: E/AndroidRuntime(31156):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Just put: `System.out.println("checked id is: " + checkedId);` in onCheckedChanged method and see what prints in console.

Comment: i checked by debugging that by clicking rg1 onCheckChange method is not called

Comment: nothing is print in console

Comment: possible duplicate of [dynamic radio buttons are not working when click the radio group to checkchangelistner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25617537/dynamic-radio-buttons-are-not-working-when-click-the-radio-group-to-checkchangel)

Comment: every time the setId of radio button is changed then how they can be duplicate.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel the edit link that you refer is also my own question which is unanswered. and my this question is updated.

Comment: `ClassCastException: android.widget.RadioGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams`. Please use proper imports.

Comment: now it is working but shows at the last of all the contents but i need this in the middle of them how can i do?

Comment: now i used the radio group from the xml and remove ll.addView now this is working fine. thanks for your help @Dhruti

Comment: as code shown i used the images and set to radio group to show them with radio button but now app crash when i click radio group and there is error that imageView can not cast to radio button. can u help me please regarding this issue? @Dhruti

Comment: The error may be at `RadioButton rbtn=(RadioButton)group.getChildAt(i);` . Make sure you have no imageview in radio group.

Comment: yes i have images in radio group as i want to show them with radio buttons how can i make this possible

Comment: see the showNationalCan method please

Comment: If your own question is unanswered, you should improve it and for example add a bounty (which requires more reputation than you currently have), you should start a new question on the same subject. Especially not within a few hours.

Comment: i want to merge images with radio buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a minor mistake.

You have added a radio group `rg` dynamically using java code.

Then you add it and use it in wrong manner.

Replace

```
rg=dbcon.showNationalCan(rg, context,iv,voterNA);
((ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.NRG)).addView(rg);
final RadioGroup rg1=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.NRG);
```

with

```
rg=dbcon.showNationalCan(rg, context,iv,voterNA);
ll.addView(rg);
rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: is there no need to show this view in the xml? means by viewGroup we put that view in that layout and here we are not putting this view in the xml to show

Comment: @Awais Its bad practice. Clean code is to add either in xml or in java. Not in both.

Comment: rg=dbcon.showNationalCan(rg, context,iv,voterNA);
     
ll.addView(rg);
   
rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

Comment: the linear layout ll which is created is also dynamic. is i have to get layout by the xml?

Comment: Yes @Awais . If you create any view through java code, you must use addView() for that. So please add your linear layout in the existing RelativeLayout  after you add radio group to it.

Comment: 'LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.NLinearLayout);'
i used this time but still same result and nothing in shown

Comment: now the app crash with fatal exception null pointer exception error

Comment: @Awais Post logcat if crash

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60463/discussion-on-answer-by-dhruti-dynamic-radio-group-to-checkchangelistener-is-not).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this according to my requirement if it is helpful to anyone

```
 RadioGroup ll = new RadioGroup(this);
 ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
 {
     RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(this);
     rdbtn.setId(i);
     rdbtn.setTag("your_tag");
     rdbtn.setText("radio_btn_name");
     ll.addView(rdbtn);
 }

 ll.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
 {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId) 
        {
            Log.e("conductor_radio_chnged", checkedId+"  =");
        }
 });

 ((ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.radiogroup)).addView(ll);
```